# how to display the item of my php list in a different order in AS3?

Tags: php, database, actionscript-3

I've got my AS3 code that pick and display item from my database table.

```
var products:Array;
var list:Sprite = new Sprite();

function complete(e:Event):void {
    addChild(list);
    products = JSON.parse(loader5.data) as Array;
    for(var i:int = 0; i < products.length; i++){
        createListItem(i, products[i]);
    }
    showList();
}
function createListItem(index:int, item:Object):void {

    var listItem:TextField = new TextField();
    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    myFormat.size = 25
    listItem.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
    listItem.text = item.title;
    listItem.x = 10;
    listItem.y = 140+ index * 40;
    listItem.width = 160;
    listItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
        showDetails(item);
    });
    list.addChild(listItem);
    str = item.title;

}
function showList():void {
    list.visible = true;
}
```

Item are displayed by entry order (the first one of the table is the first one in the list).

How can I do to display them in reverse (the new entry first, the old entry last) ?

Comment: What is the connection between PHP and AS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just reverse your for loop. This should work:

```
for(var i:int = 0, l:int = products.length - 1; l >= 0; i++, l--){
    createListItem(i, products[l]);
}
```